# Can't verify Apple Server Notification JWT Token

Tags: php, symfony, jwt, in-app-purchase, app-store

I'm trying to validate an Apple Server Notification V2 (Sandbox) with a php library:
https://github.com/web-token/jwt-framework

Based on the documentation: https://web-token.spomky-labs.com/v/v2.x/the-components/signed-tokens-jws/jws-loading I thought this should do the job:

```
$jwt = 'eyJh...';
$jwk = JWKFactory::createFromCertificateFile('AppleRootCA-G3.cer');

$algorithmManager = new AlgorithmManager([
    new ES256(),
]);

$jwsVerifier = new JWSVerifier(
    $algorithmManager
);

$serializerManager = new JWSSerializerManager([
    new CompactSerializer(),
]);

$jws = $serializerManager->unserialize($jwt);
$isVerified = $jwsVerifier->verifyWithKey($jws, $jwk, 0);
```

Still it doesn't receive a positive verification. I've debugged it onto this point:

```
$result = openssl_verify($input, $der, $pem, $this->getHashAlgorithm());
```

Which will give false but no content in openssl_error_string()

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the header of the JWT ? All informations are in it to know witch alg to use to verify the signature. You have to use the the cert (or public key) corresponding to the private key which generate the signature